# What is the PHP PATH variable and how to I add to it?

Tags: php, path, pear

Normally google is my friend for these kind of newbie problems, and I'm pretty proud of myself learning as I go without really needing to ask any questions in terms of PHP stuff, but this one's got me stumped. Trying to install a version of PEAR that supersedes my host's copy, which is hideously outdated. Apparently "pear's binary (bin) directory should be in your PATH variable." I don't know what that means or how to edit it, and supplementary to that, wether that will actually solve my problem of an outdated version of pear being on my root server. Any advice in either of these areas would be greatly welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they are talking about the OS's `PATH` environment variable, not PHP's include path (binaries [`bin`] are run by the OS, not parsed by PHP) Unfortunately, since you are in a shared hosting environment, you cannot change this environment variable in a permanent fashion. If you do have shell access though, you can modify your `.profile` file set the `PATH` variable.

You can use [`getenv()`](http://php.net/getenv) and [`putenv()`](http://php.net/putenv) to retrieve and set the PATH variable, but this will be reset on each script run.

That said, you do not need the `PATH` variables set to use PEAR. If you have a PEAR install on your development computer, you can upload the `pear` folder onto your host and modify the `include_path` at runtime to point to your own "install" using [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/set_include_path)

```
$pearInstallPath = realpath('./pear/packages');
set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . $pearInstallPath);
```

Comment: ah this is what I was after. I've installed it on my server and added packages using the web interface. The main objective was to be able to use the packages at runtime. Say my pear folder is /pear/PEAR/, would I use

`set_include_path('/pear/PEAR' . PATH_SEPARATOR
                 . get_include_path());`?

Comment: @Leon Aves: Be careful when setting the `include_path`. I would recommend always keeping the current directory (`.`) first in the list. But, yes, essentially... except that you need to put into your include path the `packages` directory of PEAR.

Comment: just for some context:

`crontab  crontab.disabled  data  html  pear  scc  tmp
-bash-3.2$ cd pear
-bash-3.2$ ls
PEAR  bin  index.php  pear.conf  temp
-bash-3.2$ cd PEAR
-bash-3.2$ ls
Archive  Console  HTML  HTTP  Net  OS  PEAR  PEAR.php  PEAR5.php  Structures  System.php  cache  data  docs  pearcmd.php  pearfrontendweb.php  peclcmd.php  tests`

Comment: @Leon Aves: Then your `PEAR` directory is your package directory yes.

Comment: Oh well, I assume you got it, yeah PEAR is the directory with all the packages (HTTP, NET) in. I'll try it, thanks :)

Comment: @Leon Aves: In fact, the whole process is documented here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Comment: That's what I've been trying to follow, but my stupid host has PEAR ver 1.3.2, so I cant use any of the instructions at the top of the page.

Comment: @Leon Aves: At the bottom there are instructions for a remote host using PEAR_RemoteInstaller.

Comment: But it's only for PEAR 1.4.3+

Comment: @Leon Aves: PEAR 1.4.3+ on your development machine... It remotely installs a remote version of PEAR via FTP. The version installed on the remote host is not important.

Comment: Ah I don't know enough about any of this stuff to be doing it. I just really needed HTTP_Request. :P

Answer (score 1):

The PATH variable that's being referred to doesn't actually have anything to do with PHP.

The PATH is the list of directories that your shell will look in to find a command you run on the command line.  So, this is talking about making the shell find the right path when you run `pear` on the command line.

Assuming you're using bash, one way to change this is to add a line like

```
export PATH=/path/to/pear/bin:$PATH
```

to a .bash_profile or .profile file in your home directory.

Comment: I'm running into issues with this. I've created a .profile (there wasn't one) in my home dir and gave it this "export PATH=/Users/ssword/pear/bin:$PATH". No Dice. During my pear install it stated "** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to** use '/Users/ssword/pear/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/Users/ssword/pear/bin' to your PATH environment variable.". Pretty straight forward, the problem is I've done that and it doesn't work. It's still stating "-bash: pear: command not found" when I use the pear cmd.

Comment: When I run echo $PATH it spits out "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/ssword/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/ssword/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/Users/ssword/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/ssword/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin". I don't know where these paths are being declared. I understand the concept of setting your $PATH variable, but it appears something is off and I wouldn't be surprised if it was right under my nose. Any ideas as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Found a solution: Bash has a load order: ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile. So my newly create .profile wasn't being loaded because my path variable stuff was in .bash_login. Added my new path to the .bash_login and now I'm running pear commands like a bawse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getenv('PATH'); // for get PATH varibale
putenv('PATH=./'); // for set path variable
```

[getenv](http://php.net/getenv), [putenv](http://php.net/setenv)